# can we send variable from controller to ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

Here in my controller i used my code like this in order to identify the success and failure,here is my code

```
if($data)
{

   echo $bill_no;

}
else
{
   echo "NO";

}
```

`$bill_no`  contains value like this `000231` and am passing that variable to the `ajax` like this

```
          if(msg == $bill_no)
          {


            console.log(msg);
            //window.location = "<?php echo base_url();?>app/admin_control";
            toastr.success('Token No is', 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000})

          }
          else if(msg =='NO')
          {
            window.location = "<?php echo base_url();?>app/admin_control";
            toastr.error('inserstion failed', 'Inconceivable!', {timeOut: 5000})
          }
```

but here am getting an error like `$bill_no` is not defined and it gets success if i choose `echo "YES"` instead of giving `$bill_no`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In scripting code you cant pass php variable like this `if(msg == $bill_no)`, it should be like below...

```
if(msg == "<?php echo  $bill_no; ?>")
```

Comment: the same code is not working on server getting error like `unterminated string literal`

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code

var bill_no = "";

if(msg == bill_no)
          {

```
        console.log(msg);
        //window.location = "<?php echo base_url();?>app/admin_control";
        toastr.success('Token No is', 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000})

      }
      else if(msg =='NO')
      {
        window.location = "<?php echo base_url();?>app/admin_control";
        toastr.error('inserstion failed', 'Inconceivable!', {timeOut: 5000})
      }
```

Comment: var bill_no =  "<?php echo  $bill_no; ?>";

Comment: the same code is not working on server getting error like unterminated string literal